# Mouseover effect to push element away on touchscreen

Tags: jquery, html, touch, mouseover, interactive

I am using this script to make an item jump away when the mouse gets close:

```
$("button").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css({
        left:(Math.random()*80)+"%",
        top:(Math.random()*80)+"%",
    });
});
```

I was wondering if there was a way to replicate this for a touchscreen?

Also this script where an image chases the mouse around:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
$("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

A touchscreen doesn't have a hover option so I don't think it is possible. Touchscreens sure have a click option so maybe that should work but as far as I know, touchscreens don't have mouseover events.